# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

```
    TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. 
at SchoolBookV2_fla::MainTimeline/dragObject1()[SchoolBookV2_fla.MainTimeline::frame18:50]
```

I am trying out some simple drag and drop. But it seems to be giving me this error. 
Can somebody please assist me with solving it? 
It looks like it's taking in the variable v as null ref. 
Is it suppose to be sequenced differently?

Code:

```
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var bag : Sprite = new Sprite ();
var book1: Sprite = new Sprite ();
var book2: Sprite = new Sprite ();
var book3: Sprite = new Sprite ();
var book4: Sprite = new Sprite ();
var totalArray: Array = new Array ();
var v:int = 0;

bag.graphics.beginFill(0xFF6666);
bag.graphics.drawRect( 30,30, 100, 150);
bag.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bag);

book1.graphics.beginFill(0xCC6666);
book1.graphics.drawRect(300,300, 100, 150);
book1.graphics.endFill();
addChild(book1);

book2.graphics.beginFill(0xCC6666);
book2.graphics.drawRect( 150,150, 100, 150);
book2.graphics.endFill();
addChild(book2);

book3.graphics.beginFill(0xCC6666);
book3.graphics.drawRect( 200,200, 100, 150);
book3.graphics.endFill();
addChild(book3);

book4.graphics.beginFill(0xCC6666);
book4.graphics.drawRect( 80,80, 100, 150);
book4.graphics.endFill();
addChild(book4);

totalArray[totalArray.length] = book1;
totalArray[totalArray.length] = book2;
totalArray[totalArray.length] = book3;
totalArray[totalArray.length] = book4;

for (v; v < totalArray.length; v++)
{
    trace(totalArray.length);
    totalArray[v].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdragObject1);
    totalArray[v].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject1);
    function dragObject1(e:MouseEvent)
    {

        totalArray[v].startDrag();
    }

    function stopdragObject1(l:MouseEvent)
    {
        totalArray[v].startDrag(false);
        trace("exists");
        if (totalArray[v].hitTestObject(bag))
        {

            totalArray[v].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdragObject1);
            totalArray[v].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject1);
            trace("itworks");
            totalArray[v].x = xPos;
            totalArray[v].y = yPos;
            trace("it doesn'twork");
        }
        else
        {
            totalArray[v].x = xPos;
            totalArray[v].y = yPos;
            trace("it doesn'twork");
        }

        totalArray[v].stopDrag();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures inside for loops are bad mojo. When the event handler is called it will use the value of v for the last iteration of the loop.

Make the `dragObject1` and `stioDragObject1` functions normal functions and access the element  through `event.target`

```
for (v; v < totalArray.length; v++)
{
    trace(totalArray.length);
    totalArray[v].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdragObject1);
    totalArray[v].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject1);
}

private function dragObject1(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.target.startDrag();
}

private function stopdragObject1(l:MouseEvent)
{
    var sprite:Sprite = l.target as Sprite;

    if (sprite.hitTestObject(bag))
    {
        sprite.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdragObject1);
        sprite.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject1);

        sprite.x = xPos;
        sprite.y = yPos;
    }
    else
    {
        sprite.x = xPos;
        sprite.y = yPos;
    }

    sprite.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: cool thx a bunch. it did work out fine. but I have a question if i want to remove the box that was placed in the bag how do i do that?

Comment: If it is a child of the `bag` then you can just remove it inside the `hitTestObject` check with `bag.removeChild(sprite)`; or you can just remove it from it's parent by `sprite.parent.removeChild(sprite);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things of issue here, though I cannot pinpoint what exactly is causing the error.

First and foremost, you should never instantiate functions within a loop like that. Please read my answer for [AS3 loop doen't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617223/as3-loop-doent-work/14618960#14618960) to better understand why. Basically: it is a memory nightmare.

Second, and this may actually be your issue, `v` does not refer to the object being selected when dragging. You see, after the loop runs (which will likely happen in a few milliseconds), v equals `totalArray.length`. `totalArray[ totalArray.length ]` cannot possible exist because an array index starts at 0, but length starts at 1. So that may be the issue.

Here's what you should do:

1. Move the functions out of the loop. It is unnecessary, a waste of memory, and you cannot call them outside of the loop
2. In the functions, instead of calling `totalArray[v]` as you are now, do this `var cur:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;` and then refer to `cur` instead. That will retrieve the object that was actually selected.

Beyond that, I really suggest you read up on how scope works. You seem to have a very basic grasp of what and how it works, but it is far from adequate.

Comment: oh thank you very much for pin pointing the problem. I actually did read up on the variable scopes. and I actually also moved the functions out but I didn't know how would I connect them to the array objects. XP. but thanks a lot for the detailed answer I am just starting out with programming.